# Symfony delete ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

I have a problem when I want delete a register with Ajax and Symfony, in template Twig.

```
<tbody>
    {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a class="delete btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data-playgroup-id="{{ entity.id }}" ></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".delete").click(function(){
        var pid = $(this).attr("data-playgroup-id");

        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
            if(result){
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: '{{path('playergroup_delete', { 'id': pid}) }}',
                    type: 'delete', 
                    success: function(result) {
                        console.log('Delete');
                    },
                    error: function(e){
                        console.log(e.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I receive the next error:

Variable "pid" does not exists.

Thanks!

Comment: Your url property looks funky.  Review the quotes, and what the output should be... `var url = "{{path('playergroup_delete', { 'id': " + pid + "}) }}"`

Comment: @PhilCooper it does not, it's twig syntax

Comment: @jean I stand corrected!

Comment: @PhilCooper not always.. It's not a good practice, but you could write inline javascript and use Twig to output variables or routes inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MouradK say you ar passing a variable in a twig function (server side) and you are getting this variable using javascript (client side).
to solve this do something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".delete").click(function(){
        var pid = $(this).attr("data-playgroup-id");

        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
            url = '{{path('playergroup_delete', { 'id': 0}) }}';
            url = $url.replace("0",pid);
            if(result){
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: url,
                    type: 'delete', 
                    success: function(result) {
                        console.log('Delete');
                    },
                    error: function(e){
                        console.log(e.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: about something like this

Comment: Yes, that found !

How could tell the 'type' attribute Ajax it can be delete and also get.

As the routing.yml .

pg_delete:
    path:     /{id}/delete
    defaults: { _controller: "MyAppBundle" }
    requirements: { _method: get|delete }

For example: 

type: 'get|delete';

Comment: Why after removing not redirects to the url that assigned ?
On the controller function that deletes the record , returns :

`playergroup_delete:
    path:     /{id}/delete
    defaults: { _controller: "MyAppBundle:PlayerGroup:delete" }
    requirements: { _method: get|delete }`

Controller:
 
`return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('playergroup'));`

Comment: That found: 

`success: function(result) {
     location.href = '{{path('playergroup')}}';
 }`

Answer (score 0):

It means that you did not pass the `pid` variable to your Twig template.

Pass it trough the controller and you'll be fine

Comment: $pid = $em->getRespository('MyAppBundle:PlayerGroup')->find(); 

But in my indexAction i not search by id, because i only find all registers.

Answer (score 0):

The error is :

You are trying to set a variable comming from the client (javascript) in your twig template (which is a server side).

Comment: I can define the variable in controller and leave empty it?

Comment: it depends of your routing configuration, if it has a default value.